# How do I access my DatabaseContext after configuring it with Stylet

Tags: c#, wpf

I am configuring my DatabaseContext from the Stylet's IoC, but how do I access it after wards say from my VM?

Do I just need to declare DatabaseContext dbContext in the constructor and that's it or how do I do it?

I am using [Stylet framework](https://github.com/canton7/stylet/) for the MVVM on my WPF app.

```cs
protected override void ConfigureIoC(IStyletIoCBuilder builder)
{
    SetupCredentials(builder);
    ConfigureLogging(builder);
    ReadConfiguration(builder);
    SetupDatabase(builder);
}

private void SetupDatabase(IStyletIoCBuilder builder)
{
    builder
        .Bind<DatabaseContext>()
        .ToFactory(container => new DatabaseContext(_setting.ConnectionString()));
}
```

Comment: I've not used Stylet, but generally with DI frameworks you either have a parameter of the type you need in the constructor, or there is a decorator attribute you put on a class member, or you have a readonly member that gets the interface directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read this page: https://github.com/canton7/Stylet/wiki/StyletIoC-Injection

There is an attribute `[Inject]` that will get the class you need from the DI container.

something like:

```
class MyView
{
    [Inject]
    private DatabaseContext dbContext;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Oh that's interesting, am I configuring the databasecontext right?

Comment: The `Bind<>`  line in SetupDatabase looks OK to me.

Comment: I am confused about something, how does the factory handle the context passed to the VM? if the VM can stay live for a longer period without doing anything to the db? Will it timeout and I will lose the ability to perform actions or will it reconnect to the db as needed?